# How to delete from a table having two filter clause with multiple combination

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, oracle11g

```
delete from connect_customer_trans_bkp
where (order_number,client_id) in (('0000220','ASD'),
                                   ('0000221','acf'),
                                   ('0000222','ddd'));
```

*Instead of writing:*

```
delete from connect_customer_trans_bkp
where (order_number='0000220'and client_id='ASD') or 
      (order_number='0000221'and client_id='acf') or
      (order_number='0000222'and client_id='ddd');
```

Comment: Is this a question, or are you providing the answer to a question that hasn't been asked yet?

Comment: OP, just in case you weren't telling us the answer but actually asking, your first query is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Suspect concatenating would work, what's the problem with the OR option?

```
delete from connect_customer_trans_bkp
     where order_number||client_id in ('0000220ASD','0000221acf','0000222ddd');
```

Comment: Perhaps ('000022', '0ASD') isn't supposed to be deleted?